# iphone table view scrolls to bottom when launch

Tags: iphone

I am following Chapter 5 in O'Reilly Learning iPhone Programming.

When I launch the app in Xcode, the list will scroll straight away to the bottom. When I try to drag the tableview upwards, it will go back to the last row when I release my mouse.

Unfortunately I am unable to post the codes since it has many sections.

Anyone has a clue what code might have caused this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the UITableView is actually extending off the visible screen. Use the debugger to check at runtime the frame of the table view. It is not scrolling because it thinks the content is fitting. Without seeing the code though, this is just an educated guess.

Answer (score 0):

I grabbed the sample code for Chapter 5 from here: http://www.learningiphoneprogramming.com/pages/samplecode.html and I'm unable to duplicate your problem. Are you sure you didn't change any of the code? What is your Base SDK?

Comment: I am using 3.1.3 simulator. It does not work also with 3.2

Thanks for the idea about the sample codes. I did a side-by-side comparsion and I could not find any differences.

Which portion of the code should I be focusing in to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: It's a very odd problem. Are you able to run it on a device and see if you can duplicate it there?